# Does the order that Excel Workbooks were opened impact macro functionality?

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry if this is a simple question, but I have a For Next loop to swap from the currently activated Workbook to a sheet in a separate workbook based on an Input Box and then re-activating the first workbook. The code worked fine when I opened the originally activated workbook first then the second workbook, but if it is opened inversely the macro does not work. I can successfully get through the InputBox but then it runs into a 'Select method of Worksheet class failed' error. Is the Input Box worksheet selection not working?

```
Sub Test()

Dim IB As String
Dim Wb As Workbook, Wb2 As Workbook

Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each Wb2 In Application.Workbooks
        Wb2.Activate
    Next
        IB = InputBox("Enter Month number", "Worksheet selection")
        Workbooks("2021 Shipments.xlsx").Worksheets(IB).Select
    Wb.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Try adding `Workbooks("2021 Shipments.xlsx").Activate` before `Workbooks("2021 Shipments.xlsx").Worksheets(IB).Select`.

Comment: Also I'm not sure what use the `For Each Wb2 In Application.Workbooks` has.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Adding the .Activate before the InputBox seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do? In which workbook is the code located? Is `Workbooks("2021 Shipments.xlsx")` wb or wb2? Why are you selecting the worksheet and then activating another workbook?

Comment: I ***highly*** recommend reading, and applying, [How to avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).